# How to create your own compilation key in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

You have your own cmake c++ project, you need to create a compilation key and get information about it in the code.

I need something like this.

in CmakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -myTest")
```

in *.cpp

```
if(KEY == "myTest"){
    // testing code.
}
```

Comment: By "compilation key", do you mean a preprocessor definition, like `-DKEY=myTest`

Comment: @jkb where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

in CMakeLists.txt

```
add_compile_definitions(TESTING)
add_compile_options(-Wall)
```

in *.cpp

```
#ifdef TESTING
    std::cout << "testing" << std::endl;
#else
#endif
```

Comment: Modern way to add compiler option is to use add_compile_option() --> https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html?highlight=add_compile_option

Modern way to add preprocessor definition is to use add_compile_definitions() --> https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions